# how to understand initialization of 3d arrays?

Tags: c#, multidimensional-array

Been googling but can´t understand how this array is a 1,8,3 array? How can you see that X is 1, Y is 8, and Z is 3 from this array?

```
        double[,,] points =
        {
            { {-1, 0, 3}, {-1, -1, -1}, {4, 1, 1 },
            {2, 0.5, 9}, {3.5, 2, -1}, {3, 1.5, 3},
            {-1.5, 4, 2}, { 5.5, 4, -0.5}}
        };
```

Answer (score 2):

If you separate it in lines you will be able to see it clear:

```
double[,,] points ={
    { 
        {-1, 0, 3}, 
        {-1, -1, -1}, 
        {4, 1, 1 },
        {2, 0.5, 9}, 
        {3.5, 2, -1}, 
        {3, 1.5, 3},
        {-1.5, 4, 2}, 
        { 5.5, 4, -0.5}
    }
};
```

Lets go to separate it:

1º This is your array and everything it contains is this:

```
double[,,] points ={
   {//Top level element (1 dimension since there is only one array inside it)

   }
};
```

2º Inside of the top level there are eight subarrays (By now we have (1,8) dimensions):

```
double[,,] points ={
    { 
        {}, //Subarray 1 (Second Level, with 8 elements)
        {}, //Subarray 2
        {}, //Subarray 3
        {}, //Subarray 4
        {}, //Subarray 5
        {}, //Subarray 6
        {}, //Subarray 7
        {}  //Subarray 8
    }
};
```

3º Finally inside of each of 8 sub array there are three elements:

```
double[,,] points ={
    { 
        {-1, 0, 3}, //Third Level (with 3 elements)
        {-1, -1, -1}, 
        {4, 1, 1 },
        {2, 0.5, 9}, 
        {3.5, 2, -1}, 
        {3, 1.5, 3},
        {-1.5, 4, 2}, 
        { 5.5, 4, -0.5}
    }
};
```

With these, we finally have all the dimensions (1,8,3). I recommend you to format array to see them clear.

I hope it helps you.

Comment: Now it makes sense. Thanks for all answers!

Answer (score 1):

You just reformat it, basically:

```
double[,,] points =
{
    { // One top-level element
         {-1, 0, 3}, // 8 "middle-level" elements, each of which has 3 elements
         {-1, -1, -1},
         {4, 1, 1 },
         {2, 0.5, 9},
         {3.5, 2, -1},
         {3, 1.5, 3},
         {-1.5, 4, 2},
         { 5.5, 4, -0.5}
    }
};
```

Answer (score 0):

I rearranged the array and added some comments to clarify the structure:

```cs
double[,,] points =
{   // one element: X
    { // having eight elements: Y
        {-1, 0, 3}, // each having three elements: Z
        {-1, -1, -1}, 
        {4, 1, 1 },
        {2, 0.5, 9}, 
        {3.5, 2, -1}, 
        {3, 1.5, 3},
        {-1.5, 4, 2}, 
        { 5.5, 4, -0.5}
    }
};
```

The points implicit has the first element as X, second as Y and third as Z. So the number of elemets is 1, 8, 3.